# Motherboard won't post AFTER I click restart button OR do it via Windows

Tags: windows-8, motherboard, hardware-failure, reboot

As the title says, computer starts up fine from shutdown but when I try to restart it, it simply won't reboot. The fans spin, lights are on and everything is working but the motherboard won't post.

Post shows 0 0 when I try to reboot.

Ram is fine, 
motherboard CMOS battery is fine. 
I updated the motherboard BIOS.
I used new ram... I don't get it.

Comment: Have you looked into the error logs?

Comment: Have you tried swapping power supplies?  Can you give us specs on the computer please?